# Why do we not have an SE section for conspiracy debunking? Are conspiracy questions applicable here?

Tags: discussion

The reason i ask this question here, is because i can find no other platform where the question is applicable, and i thought perhaps political minded people, might actually be the most likely to also have opinions on wide of centre subjects such as propaganda and conspiracy theory.

Given that conspiracy theory is such a big problem in our current age, i am surprised nobody has yet introduced a section where conspiracy questions can be asked, and replied to by debunkers.

Conspiracy theories are described as being political in motivation:

> A conspiracy theory is an explanation for an event or situation that invokes a conspiracy by sinister and powerful groups, often political in motivation
> [conspiracy theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conspiracy_theory)

So would conspiracy theory questions be applicable here? If not, where would they be applicable? And if not applicable on any SE section, why have no Political minded people came up with a section where conspiracy theories can be debunked?

Comment: see SE.Skeptics  https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Italian Philosophers 4 MonicaAlready been there. I think Skeptic sites mostly deal with pro-Atheist subjects. I dont think they would have much time for answering questions on whether George Bush is a shapeshifting reptile or not.

Comment: @StevenIanGall Skeptics.SE will address any notable claim you can find. I’m not entirely sure off the top of my head what their definition is, but if you can find news reports, we’ll-known people, or just a lot of social media attention, that counts. One random person tweeting about shape shifting reptiles is not notable; 5000 may be.

Comment: @Bobson Ok, well since i am outnumbered i guess i must be mistaken. Thanks for the tip !

Comment: @Steven One thing that is common in all SE sites is questions should be specific, not broad. You might debunk a conspiracy theory by breaking down the problem. Each small problem might or might not be applicable to one of the hundred or so SE sites. I am not sure if they would allow you to create such a SE site but [area51.se] is the place where you can propose one.

Comment: Conspiracy theories can't be debunked; the people who buy into them implicitly reject the kind of reasoning that debunking requires. Such is life...

Comment: Obligatory XKCD comic: https://xkcd.com/258/

Comment: @StevenIanGall You're not mistaken because you're outnumbered. You're "outnumbered" by the people telling you you're wrong *because you're wrong*.

Comment: @StevenIanGall For what it's worth, there is at least [one question about shapeshifting lizard-people](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2370/are-there-reptilian-creatures-hosting-the-news) on skeptics, and it's sitting at +15. If you can find a "notable source" making this claim, you probably can ask about it as long as you take your time to carefully craft the question

Comment: @Ted Except when the conspiracy turns out to be true, like when the Epidemiologist Ian Lipkin admitted he withheld a scientific study showing mask cause a 70% reduction in viral transmission because there was a shortage of masks at the time and and they didn't want the general public buying them all up: (@ 33 minutes in) https://www.microbe.tv/twiv/twiv-special-lipkin/ - Later Fauci admitted to lying as well for the same reason https://thehill.com/changing-america/well-being/prevention-cures/502890-fauci-why-the-public-wasnt-told-to-wear-masks - If that's not a conspiracy, I don't know what is

Comment: @SurpriseDog: logic please: something that's *true* can't be debunked; it's true. But being *true* doesn't make it a *conspiracy*. Conspiracy theories are immune to *invalidation* not to *validation*. And you know what they say: even a broken clock is right twice a day.If you understood the psychology behind conspiratorial thinking you'd understand what a serious problem it is, but this isn't really the place to go into that.

Answer (score 7):

We already got a site on the Stack Exchange network for fact-checking notable claims, which includes conspiracy theories (as long as they are notable enough and falsifiable):

[Skeptics Stack Exchange](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: They already went there and they weren't terribly happy about the responses they got.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Skeptics SE site is burdened with some (expletives deleted) moderators who delight in deleting any interesting discussion, especially when it goes against their own opinions, which makes it pretty well worthless.

Comment: @jamesqf You should be aware by now that Stack Exchange is not a platform for discussions in general.

Comment: @Philipp: Yes, it is.  Observe what people actually do here, rather than trying to deny reality - and in the process, driving a lot of people away.

Comment: Yeah, no. While some people try to pretend that Stack Exchange is a hive of discussion, the vast majority of usage is in Q&A, with the majority of commentary being meta, about the Q&A, not topical, about the subject. There are a few sites where the rate is greater, but still far from making those sites "a platform for discussion in general", let alone the entire network.